# Providing constructor parameter at mapping time

Tags: c#, automapper

I have 2 classes that are interdependent of each other through a third class. I'm struggling to find a way to map them correctly using AutoMapper 
(version 6.1.1).

I've created a sample example to be has much as clear as possible of what I'm trying to achieve. The example will look silly, but understand that this a very simplified example for the purpose of this question (but behind that question is a big application which I cannot refactor easily)

```
public class PersonDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<RelationshipLinkDto> RelationshipLinks { get; set; }
}

public class RelationshipDto
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class RelationshipLinkDto
{
    public int RelationShipId { get; set; }

    public int PersondId { get; set; }

    public bool IsStrongRelationship { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see the relationship has the "IsStrongRelationship " property so it's not a simple relational-link we are used to find in a database for instance. Know that the real application have tons of those "options" property.

Here's the business representation of those objects.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<RelationshipLink> RelationshipLinks { get; set; }
}

public class Relationship
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class RelationshipLink
{
    public RelationshipLink(Relationship relationship)
    {
        Relationship = relationship;
    }

    public int RelationshipId
    {
        get { return Relationship.Id; }
    }

    private Relationship Relationship { get; }
}
```

This is where the tricky part is : is it possible to construct the business version of the RelationshipLink at mapping time since it's only at that time that I would have access to the Relationship business object required by the constructor?

Important piece of information is "how I have access to those Person objects". Both PersonDto and RelationshipDto are contained in list found inside a file and the file itself is a DtO called "FileContainerDto". Here are the Dto and Business representation of that file:

```
public class FileContainerDto
{
    public List<PersonDto> People { get; set; }

    public List<RelationshipDto> Relationships { get; set; }
}

public class FileContainer
{
    public List<Person> People { get; set; }

    public List<Relationship> Relationships { get; set; }
}
```

I already have a plan B which is to use the Ignore() option for the relationship links members. And after deserialization, I would simply create the business version of the object manually. That would be very simple, but I was  curious if Automapper was able to handle that kind of mapping itself, that would be neat :)

Comment: There is [constructor mapping](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Construction) and if that doesn't fit you can do pretty much everything with ConstructUsing.

Comment: I already thought of using these two techniques, but sadly, they are only usable at configuration time, not at mapping time. To construct the object, I need to have access to the business version of the parent dto (FileContainer) which hold the business Relationship object required by the constructor of the Relationshiplink object.

Comment: No, not really. With constructor mapping you get the source object. That might not help here, that's true. With ConstructUsing you have an overload that receives the ResolutionContext and you can use that for passing parameters. See [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper).

Comment: I thoug of using a custom resolver but I'm not sure how since the parameter that I need to pass to the RelationshipLink constructor is being resolved at the same time (as it's part of the FileContainerDto as well).

Comment: I think you don't really have a problem with AM, but with your model, and AM can't really help with that. AM does the auto part, the logic of the model is on you.

Comment: Another thing is that you can map the relationship constructor parameter from the corresponding dto and AM will apply the map for you, but again, the model must allow you to apply what AM can do.